# Encoding php form into JSON object

Tags: php, json

The application I am working on requires the user to fill up a form and he can upload multiple documents. Everytime he uploads a document, a webservice is called which returns a JSON with 'id' and 'type'. And at the end when he submits the entire form, I need to send all the data he has filled up in the form along with the document 'id' and 'type' that I have received in the previous JSON by encoding it in JSON format.

Here I have used a function that is called everytime the user uploads a document which calls a webservice which returns the JSON. I have pushed the content on the JSON on the array.

```
$idarray = array();
$typearray = array(); 
function f1(){
    include 'webservice_call.php';
    $json_string = $json_decode($response);
    $id = $json_string->id;
    $type = $json_string->ty;
        array_push($idarray, $id);
        array_push($typearray, $ty);
}
```

Now I need to send the array in the following format when the user submits the form:

```
"docls":[  
       {  
           "id":"123",
           "ty":"101",
        },
        {  
           "id":"456",
           "ty":"102",
        }
        {  
           "id":"456",
           "ty":"102",
        }
        ]
```

I am encoding it like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $json_formatted = array(
             'docls' =>  array (
                    'id' => $idarray,
                    'ty' => $typearray,         
                     ), 
               );
        echo json_encode($json_formatted);
        }
```

I am pretty sure I am not doing it right. Is there some simpler way to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$docls=array();
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($idarray); $i++) { 
$docls[] =  array (
                'id' => $idarray[$i],
                'ty' => $typearray[$i],         
                 );

}
$json_formatted['docls']=$docls;
echo json_encode($json_formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to send JSON with a form, and decode it on the receiver's end. Ulimately you'd want to have JavaScript handle JSON.